EPSG:7845 GDA2020 / GA LCC (Lambert Conformal Conic) for MapInfo Pro Version 15.0.2 - 32 bit
EPSG:7845 GDA2020 / GA LCC (Lambert Conformal Conic) for MapInfo Pro Version 15.0.2 - 32 bit
I need to add EPSG:7845 GDA2020 / GA LCC (Lambert Conformal Conic) projection into MapInfo Pro Version 15.0.2 - 32 bit  (already added to my 64 bit using Projection Editor).
I could not seems to succeed adding it to our 32-bit MapInfo version, which we mainly using for big digitizing jobs (as it is faster and not as clumsier as 64-bit).
Something along the lines:
"Australian Lamberts Conformal Conic (GDA94)", 3, 116, 7, 135, -24, -18, -36, 0, 0
"Australian Lamberts Conformal Conic (GDA2020)", 3, 9999, 7, 134, 0, -18, -36, 0, 0  (?????)

Are you getting any error messages?
